# Remove the "page" links at the bottom of a post in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have tried to remove the pagination from my post pages in wordpress:

domain/page/pageno which are actually posts.

Google is indexing them and it looks stupid to see results like "page/130" "page/131" etc.

I already have a dynamic set of page links with the full text in the footer - so the pagination is just a nuisance. What code do I need to remove/comment out to get rid of this?

I am using the twenty sixteen theme BTW. In case the code is theme specific.

Answer (score 0):

After looking everywhere I decided to run a "string find" on the "nav-links". I found the wp-includes file "links-template.php" and commented out the code for the nav links.

Worked like a charm. Hope this wont screw anything else up.